# Understanding behavior of remainder() function in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle12c

According to Oracle documentation for the remainder(n2,n1) function (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions133.htm), the remainder(n2,n1) function evaluates to = n2 - n1 * N where N = ROUND(n2/n1) and n1 != 0.

So, I would expect remainder(10,4) to return -2 using the above documented method of calculating the remainder as shown below:

```
REMAINDER(10,4)
=10 - 4 * N where N = ROUND(10/4) 
=10 - 4 * 3 since ROUND(10/4) = 3 
=10 - 12
=-2
```

However, running remainder(10,4) in Oracle 10g, 11g, and 12c returns 2 instead of -2.

Can someone please explain why the remainder(10,4) is not evaluating as per the documented method of how oracle evaluates the remainder?

Additional information: This behavior happens for every other n2 where n2 is a multiple of n1 / 2. It can be verified by running the following SQL where each remainder function value should match the value next to it. But it only matches for every other value of n2.
Running the SQL:

```
select
remainder(2,4), 2-4*round(2/4),--OUTPUT:2, -2
remainder(6,4),6-4*round(6/4), --OUTPUT: -2, -2
remainder(10,4),10-4*round(10/4),--OUTPUT: 2, -2
remainder(14,4),14-4*round(14/4)--OUTPUT: -2, -2
from dual
```

Comment: Apparently `ROUND(2.5)` returns 3 when called directly, but whatever rounding is being done in the `REMAINDER` function causes the result of `ROUND(2.5)` to be 2. You might want to look at the `MOD` function.

Comment: @BobJarvis - not sure what you mean by "apparently". If you never worked with Oracle, let others opine. `Round(10/4)` is `3` in Oracle.

Comment: I work with Oracle every day. And while `ROUND(2.5)` may return 3 (as it clearly does), explain why `REMAINDER(10,4)` is 2 rather than -2. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The people who wrote the documentation (who seem not to recall some definitions from arithmetic) themselves seem unsure about what they wrote. On the one hand, early in the explanation they do mention `ROUND` - yet later when they give a more formal definition they say

> •If n1 != 0, then the remainder is n2 - (n1*N) where N is the integer
>   nearest n2/n1

"Integer nearest" is not formally defined in arithmetic, and indeed one is permitted to use that name for round(x) except when the fractional part of x is exactly 0.5, in which case "integer nearest" is ambiguous and one may choose to use "round down" as their own definition of "integer nearest."

Don't get too upset with such inconsistencies in the documentation, if you can. You will see many more.

**However**: What is MUCH worse is that the behavior is inconsistent. I use Oracle 12.1, and on my machine I just tried and I get

```
remainder(10, 4) =  2
remainder( 6, 4) = -2
```

No rhyme or reason. Much better to do your own division, using FLOOR and such.

*Edit* - Or maybe there is some reason; perhaps they use a definition of "nearest integer" to mean, in the case of a tie, the nearest **even** integer. Still producing unexpected results, best not to use Oracle's REMAINDER() function.

Comment: Looked into the ROUND() documentation (<http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions135.htm>). It mentions that for NUMBER type the ROUND() always rounds away from 0 (omitted from 11g). So ROUND(2.5) = 3 as expected when run by itself. However, it looks like when the REMAINDER() function is using ROUND() internally, then it may be deviating from this behavior.  This deviation would happen when while calling ROUND(N2/N1) inside REMAINDER() it would convert N2/N1 to a non-NUMBER type (e.g BINARY_FLOAT). If true then it would evaluate ROUND(10/4) to even (to 2 instead of 3).

Comment: @lazyPanda - I very strongly doubt that the internal implementation of REMAINDER calls the ROUND function. I think it computes it directly, in a manner close to your description - "nearest integer", when in doubt, is the "nearest **even** integer". This probably uses some fundamental machine-language functions, rather than higher-level ROUND.

Comment: you are correct about it being the nearest even integer when n2/n1 equals x.5. Found this in the 11g documentation: If n1 != 0, then the remainder is n2 - (n1*N) where N is the integer nearest n2/n1. **If n2/n1 equals x.5, then N is the nearest even integer**. The documentation is inconsistent across versions. The ROUND() function has more information in 10 g documentation while the REMAINDER() function has more information in the 11g documentation.

Comment: @lazyPanda which is a bizarre definition of the mathematical remainder; surely it ought to be n2 - (floor(n2/n1)*n1)?! What were they thinking when they implemented it to the nearest even integer rather than floor?!

Comment: Although, thinking about it, that's basically the definition of MOD(n2, n1).

Comment: @Boneist - Weird (bizarre) definitions all around, and the more I research it the more I find out that some of them are not limited to Oracle. For one thing, MOD and REMAINDER should be **identical** - the definition of  MOD, in arithmetic, is as the "remainder" of integer division. Then: In math, the remainder is always non-negative; `n2-floor(n2/n1)*n1` is not the right definition in arithmetic (this definition will have the sign of the reminder the same as `sign(n1))`, but apparently Don Knuth used this non-mathematical, "floor" definition. Oracle uses it for MOD but not for REMAINDER.

Comment: @mathguy yeah, I hadn't considered negative numbers, then encountered them in the documentation for MOD and then my brain went \*poof\*! and I gave up! *{;-)

Comment: Or actually that's not even what Oracle uses for negative numbers (for MOD). It seems in Oracle the sign of MOD is the same as the sign of `n1` - not even the "floored division" of Don Knuth. If I ever do arithmetic (number theory, integer arithmetic) in Oracle or pretty much in any other software, I'll make sure to test MOD and write my own if it's different from the mathematical definition, which is likely to be the case in most software from what I'm reading. (And there I was, thinking `exp(0, 0) = 1` will be the only annoying thing I'll have to put up with!) :-)